# JSF 2.0: Preserving component state across multiple views

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, state

The web application I am developing using MyFaces 2.0.3 / PrimeFaces 2.2RC2 is divided into a content and a navigation area. In the navigation area, which is included into multiple pages using templating (i.e. `<ui:define>`), there are some widgets (e.g. a navigation tree, collapsible panels etc.) of which I want to preserve the component state across views.

For example, let's say I am on the home page. When I navigate to a product details page by clicking on a product in the navigation tree, my Java code triggers a redirect using

```
navigationHandler.handleNavigation(context, null,
  "/detailspage.jsf?faces-redirect=true")
```

Another way of getting to that details page would be by directly clicking on a product teaser that is shown on the home page. The corresponding `<h:link>` would lead us to the details page.

In both cases, the expansion state of my navigation tree (a PrimeFaces tree component) and my collapsible panels is lost. I understand this is because the redirect / `h:link` results in the creation of a new view.

What is the best way of dealing with this? I am already using MyFaces Orchestra in my project along with its conversation scope, but I am not sure if this is of any help here (since I'd have to bind the expansion/collapsed state of the widgets to a backing bean... but as far as I know, this is not possible). Is there a way of telling JSF which component states to propagate to the next view, assuming that the same component exists in that view?

I guess I could need a pointer into the right direction here. Thanks!

---

**Update 1:** I just tried binding the panels and the tree to a session-scoped bean, but this seems to have no effect. Also, I guess I would have to bind all child components (if any) manually, so this doesn't seem like the way to go.

**Update 2:** Binding UI components to non-request scoped beans is not a good idea (see link I posted in a comment below). If there is no easier approach, I might have to proceed as follows:

- When a panel is collapsed or the tree is expanded, save the current state in a session-scoped backing bean (!= the UI component itself)
- The components' states are stored in a map. The map key is the component's (hopefully) unique, relative ID. I cannot use the whole absolute component path here, since the IDs of the parent naming containers might change if the view changes, assuming these IDs are generated programmatically.
- As soon as a new view gets constructed, retrieve the components' states from the map and apply them to the components. For example, in case of the panels, I can set the `collapsed` attribute to a value retrieved from my session-scoped backing bean.

**Update 3:** I got it working as described above. To sum it up, the solution is to store the relevant properties in a session-scoped bean instead of making the entire UIComponent session-scoped. Then, when the component is re-constructed after navigation has occurred, set the attribute values by retrieving the saved properties (using EL), e.g.

```
<p:panel collapsed="#{backingBean.collapsedState}" ... />
```

(This is a simplified example. Since I am using multiple panels, I am using a map to store these properties, as described above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use session-scoped beans.

Comment: Binding the UI components to a session-scoped bean does **NOT** work. This results in an IllegalStateException as soon as I refresh the page: `Component ID j_idt12:j_idt13:j_idt14 has already been found in the view.`

_Correction:_ I just tested this again with a standalone panel and now it's working. Now let's figure out why it doesn't work with my other panels...

Comment: Ok, so binding components to session-scoped beans is apparently a no-go. See http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2479&start=0#p11946 and http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/myfaces-orchestra-core/component-bindings.html: 

"In order to avoid the lifecycle mismatch between components and beans, any bean that stores a component binding must be request-scoped."

Comment: Got it working by saving only the relevant properties in the session-scoped bean (instead of making the whole UIComponent session-scoped). See my updates above.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by collapsible panels? I ask because there is a  component that is closable as well as a  component.  I am using  in the navigation pane in my project. The accordianPanel has an attribute named "activeIndex". Here's what I did in my sessionBean to maintain the state of my accordion tabs:

```
 private int tabIndex; //declared a private variable

    public SessionBean() {
       tabIndex = 100; //set the initial tab index to 100 so all tabs are closed when page loads.
    }

    public int getTabIndex(){
       return tabIndex;
    }

    public void setTabIndex(int tabIndex){
       this.tabIndex=tabIndex;
    }

in my navigation pane:



<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="#{sessionBean.tabIndex}" collapsible="true" autoHeight="false">
    <p:tab title="#{tab1_title}">
       <h:commandLink value="link here" action="target_page?faces-redirect=true" /><br/>
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="#{tab2_title}">
       <h:commandLink value="link here" action="target_page?faces-redirect=true" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="#{tab3_title}">
       <h:commandLink value="link here" action="target_page?faces-redirect=true" />
    </p:tab>
 </p:accordionPanel>
```

I'm not using the tree component for navigation as that presented my project with some difficulties that were easily overcome by using the accordionPanel, so I can't speak to that part of your navigation.

Comment: With "collapsible panels", I meant regular `<p:panel>` instances. So my solution for the panels is similar to yours, namely retrieving the `collapsed` value from the session-scoped backing bean: `<p:panel collapsed="#{backingBean.collapsedState}" toggleListener="#{backingBean.onToggle}">`. The only difference here is that you also need a toggle listener which updates the collapsed state in the backing bean, because otherwise the collapse action will not be propagated to the server side (since it's client-side JavaScript).

Comment: For the tree, the approach is similar; here, instead of the toggle listener, you need select, expand and collapse listeners to maintain state on the server-side. In these listeners, simply update the tree nodes (e.g. `treeNode.setExpanded(true)`) to propagate client state to the server. The next time the tree is re-built on a page reload, these values in the tree nodes will be used to initialize the new tree. However, I should note that in PrimeFaces 2.2RC2, the expand and collapse listeners seem to be broken.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind since we would rather use the tree in our navigation system.  Thanks for the tip.